# How do I blend a digital texture into a photo to give a canvas or rough paper effect?

Tags: effect, image-manipulation, texture

I have seen other photographers use deviantart art work as backdrops in their photography with exotic outcomes. I haven't been successful in figuring out how this is done. Would anyone please share your own experience or links to tutorials or helpful resources? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please link us to an example of what you're refering to, Sri? That way we can get a screenshot added to your question for you.

Comment: Yes, it would be very helpful to know what you mean by "exotic outcomes". That sounds like something more than a backdrop. And is there something particular about this Web site that you mean or are you just using it as an example of digital art?

Comment: Also, please be aware of copyright issues here — make sure the work you are incorporating in your photo is licensed for sharing.

Comment: I believe they're called textures. I can think of the photographs shown on this page:https://www.facebook.com/cristi.n.foto.  (Dani Dragoescu's picture). Sorry cannot think of a better way for showing what I need to demonstrate.

Comment: This one? https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=348583388615020&set=a.142253505914677.30732.100003900858876&type=1&theater

Comment: here we go:  https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=321753511298008&set=a.142253505914677.30732.100003900858876&type=3&theater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textures are simply images of other flat or not so flat subjects added to a conventional color or B&W image.  Here's an example of one of mine: [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/37177474@N03/5032042748/in/photolist-8EEwZJ-7Rjb8r-9KmVTN-7ScZ1g-ds44gF-7KkUXL-dvTsJN-bgk5p2-7NubTC-9srmam-dkCKwH-8EFDk7-8EEFJ1-9cX7Dc-9kGPg5-7KKNnt-7VbcPb-9HuVL7-8WmDbA-9ixtNR-9t6kL3-9kTkRX-9D9iXC-9egGK4-8Wt7QJ-8T2akQ-9o7juN-8UVLUt-7JbjCe-7KKJa6-9o78Nc-9npDac-9jht9P-7J2sSe-9mfP6F-8WfsVq-9zbKr5-7D1G7u-aF7Faj-7RyWYS-dnDCfp-8Pkmgo-dkK941-8WN3SG-dooniU-9o7f1o-9DHV4n-7XKrFG-8fwgAX-drPDZ8-9ztuWe)

So to do this you need an image and at least one texture image.

1.) Open both in Photoshop
2.) Drag the texture layer over to the image you want to add it too. 
3.) Change the blend mode of the layer to what is appropriate for the result your looking for.

Using multiple textures as in the example above, you add multiple texture layers and change their layer modes and opacities to achieve the effect you want.   Simple and fun to do.

In my example image there were 6 textures applied in 14 layers in various different blending modes.  I like to use Multiply, Color Dodge, Soft Light, Divide, as good places to start, but because the layer modes are very dependent on the textures you use, this is very much the artistic part of the process.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. I have since been able to find some tutorials as well. Very cool.

Comment: @Sri If this answers your question please mark the question answered. Providing an up vote is also a normal part of that process.

Comment: Thank you R Hall for the note. Sorry new to the process. Can't vote yet with my curr reputation.

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop, under the `Filters` menu, there is a section of textures. It is very easy to add a canvas or craquelure texture to your image.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I am familiar with what you are describing. I was looking for adding "textures" to your images from deviantart or any other source for that matter.